# Is running Umbraco within an ASP.NET Core API possible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, umbraco

Is it possible to utilize Umbraco with an **ASP.NET Core API** project?
Can these two techs work together or do I have to use .NET 4.x ?

:::::::::::::::::::::::: UPDATE ::::::::::::::::::::::::

**I accepted @mortenbock's answer, but I strongly suggest to people interested in this question to also read the comments below, where @Tseng has provided some very useful answers.**

Comment: ASP.NET Core and .NET Framework 4.x are **not mutually exclusive** (at least for now, until/if Microsoft deprecate ASP.NET core on the full framework). ASP.NET Core is a webstack, .NET Framework and .NET Core  are runtimes. They have no connection. That being said, both ASP.NET Core 1.x as well as ASP.NET Core 2.x runs on both, .NET Core and .NET Framework!

Comment: Also please avoid question titles which are a **mere a list of keywords**, they are not helpful to people who look through the list and may or may no have an answer for you. I rephrased the title for you, which makes it more clear what the question is about

Comment: Thank you for editing my question - I'll try to use more precise questions in the future. Could you please elaborate a bit? As far as I know, the backwards compatibility of ASP.NET Core with the old .NET is one of the points of focus of the dedicated team. So what you say is, that it IS POSSIBLE to use those two techs combined, right? I have doubts, because just a few minutes ago I read something quite contrary. Also please make your comment an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: You can run ASP.NET Core on .NET Core (=portable, runs on linux) or you can run ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework (windows only, mono for linux/mac). ASP.NET Core is a complete rewrite of ASP.NET, so does umbraco runs with it? **Probably not**, if its not been ported yet for ASP.NET Core. Check their tracker http://issues.umbraco.org/dashboard or ask the their support

Comment: Taking into consideration everything you've written up till now, I see it like this: Umbraco runs on old .NET Framework, but I can build an ASP.NET Core WebApp and download an Umbraco NuGet and deploy the whole thing on a Windows server and it will run fine. Is this a valid assumption?

Comment: If Ubraco supports ASP.NET Core yes. While ASP.NET Core is independent of .NET Core and .NET Framework its still a rewrite, with different API then ASP.NET 4 (without **Core**). But if it use anything from `System.Web.*` namespace, you will probably be out of luck. All dependencies on `System.Web.*` have been removed from ASP.NET Core, because they depend on IIS and to make ASP.NET Core portable, it had to go

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Umbraco will not run on .Net Core in the current version 7.x

I believe they are working towards making it possible in version 9, which is still a long way off.

See the [System requirements for Umbraco 8](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Requirements/): IIS is still required and it will not run on ASP.NET Core

Shannon Deminick has been doing some PoC work on it: [his blog post about "Umbraco CLI running on ASP.NET Core" has more details](https://shazwazza.com/post/umbraco-cli-running-on-aspnet-core/)

You could use Umbraco as a headless CMS in a separate application, and then consume the content from you .Net Core application via REST or similar. At codegarden 2016 an example [to use Umbraco CMS as an headless cms with custom frontend was shown](https://video.twentythree.net/avoncom-an-umbraco-approach-to-a-headless-cms)